# Java, How do i add values to Object array

Tags: java, arrays, codenameone

I need to add values to an array of objects dynamically and pass that array variable to a function.

If I add values manually it works fine.

```
Object[][] listData = {{"Cheese", "Pepperoni", "Black Olives"},{"Cheese",    
"Pepperoni", "Black Olives"}};
```

This is the function that needs to use **listData** .

```
TableModel tblModel = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Date", "Action", "Amount"}, listData);
```

but how can I add values into **listData** from a for loop?

```
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> sampleArray =   (ArrayList)myPremiumspaid.get("Data"); 
for(int x =0; x<sampleArray.size(); x++)
 {
    //sampleArray.get(x).get("YearMonth");
   //listData[][] = "";  stuck here
 }
```

Comment: where do you get the values for the array from?

Comment: Java arrays have a fixed length; what do you mean "add values ... dynamically"?

Comment: What is the type of ```sampleArray``` ?

Comment: ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> sampleArray

Comment: i want to pull certain values from the Map, then populate Object[][], please check my updated question

Comment: What does ```get("YearMonth")``` actually return, as in, strong type. What is stored in the map?

Comment: check the format of the Map, It returns an Object but i can simply convert that into a String, This is not question here, My problem is adding values to Object[][] listData, Is it possible or not?

Comment: @Rhay //listData[0][x] = "", doesnt work for me

Comment: @YungA why not? you can't fill it line per line/ row per row?

Comment: `Object[][] listData; listData[0][1] = {"Cheese", "Pepperoni", "Black Olives"};`

illegal start of expression.

Comment: but `Object[][] foo = new Object[2][2];` `String[] bar = {"Cheese", "Pepperoni", "Black Olives"};` and then `foo[0][0] =bar;` should be fine.

Comment: the problem with this is that i don't want to specify size of the array. that's why i want populate it using a for loop

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are **fixed sized**, after creating the array Object, you can't update it's size/ enlarge it's size.
So the purpose to be dynamic size or auto growing sized, you need to use **List** ie. **ArrayList**.

```
Object[][] listData = {{"Cheese", "Pepperoni", "Black Olives"},{"Cheese",    
"Pepperoni", "Black Olives"}};
```

Instead:

```
List<List<Object>> listData=new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
listData.add(Arrays.asList("Cheese", "Pepperoni", "Black Olives"));
listData.add(Arrays.asList("Cheese", "Pepperoni", "Black Olives"));
```

But this ArrayList needs to be passed into a function which is taking array, so, you could convert the **ArrayList** to **array object**.

```
TableModel tblModel = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Date", "Action", "Amount"}, (Object[][]) listData.toArray());
```

> but how can I add values into listData from a for loop?
>   Now you could do it as follows:

```
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> sampleArray =   (ArrayList)myPremiumspaid.get("Data"); 
for(int x =0; x<sampleArray.size(); x++)
 {
    //sampleArray.get(x).get("YearMonth");
   listData.get(x).add(sampleArray.get(x).get("YearMonth"));
 }
```

Codename One's `DefaultTableModel` has an [addRow](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow-java.lang.Object...-) method that accepts an array or series of Objects so just using:

```
((DefaultTableModel)tblModel).addRow("Cheese", "Pepperoni", "Black Olives");
```

Should work.

Comment: FYI added a small refinement to the answer at the bottom referring to `DefaultTableModel` in Codename One

Comment: I managed to specify the size of listData array from the size of my returned data (sampleArray)

Comment: if you define the size of listData  by the size of returned data of sampleArray, if you need to add more data from another object, you will not be able to extend the size of array because after creating the array, u cant extend it. So if you need dynamic growable size, you should use ArrayList.